# html code with entered values

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have

```
<div aura:id="form">
    <lightning:input type="text" placeholder="???" label="x" variant="label-hidden" name="x" aura:id="x" />
</div>

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
```

in controller:

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var body = component.find("form");
    console.log(body.getElement().outerHTML);
}
```

Is it possible to get html code of the div with input and its value?

What I want is to get a String with html code to render it in aura:unescapedHtml and then use it further with entered value. This is only a sample code, the component is much more complex with many fields (inputs and checkboxes)

Comment: You cannot access the DOM elements of component belonging to foreign namespace. If you can provide us enough information on what needs to be done, we can help you better.

Comment: what I want to achieve is to have a component with table. User should fill in this table with values and then click a button which should grab html code of this component and put it to variable. Then I need to work with the html code outside lightning component, like rendering pdf file, ...